# org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: Could not set field value with Composite Key

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

Using Spring Boot with Hibernate JPA

I am having trouble accessing a DAO for an @Entity which has a composite key where one of the columns is a foreign key. It's giving me 
`org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: Could not set field value [...] by reflection` when I try to do a findOne() using the DAO.

So I have two MySQL relations, `all_contacts`  and `contact_phones`, represented in order here:

[image: all_contacts] [image: contact_phones]

`contact_phones` has a composite primary key consisting of `contactid` + `number`, of those two, `contactId` is also a foreign key for the same value in `all_contacts`. I've established the relationship using the proper `@OneToMany` and `@ManyToOne` annotations

**Entity for all_contacts:**

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "all_contacts")
    public class Contact {

      @Column(name="userid", columnDefinition ="bigint(13)")
      private BigInteger userId;

      @Id
      @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
      @Column(name="contactid", columnDefinition ="bigint(13)")
      private BigInteger contactId;


     @OneToMany(mappedBy = "contact", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
     @ElementCollection(targetClass=ContactPhones.class)
     private Set<ContactPhones> phones = new HashSet<ContactPhones>(0);

    // the rest of the fields, including getters and setters

    }
```

**Entity for contact_phones:**

```
@Entity
@Table( name ="contact_phones")
@IdClass(ContactPhonesKey.class)
public class ContactPhones {


  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name="contactid", nullable = false)
  @Id
  private Contact contact;

  @Column(name="phone_type", columnDefinition = "")
  private String phoneType;

  @Id
  @Column(columnDefinition ="bigint(13)")
  private BigInteger number;

  // getters and setters
}
```

And, because the primary key of the contact_phones class was composite (hence the `@IdClass(ContactPhonesKey.class)` ), I was forced to create a Key class to direct it:

**Class for ContactPhonesKey:**

```
public class ContactPhonesKey implements Serializable {

  private Contact contact;
  private String number;

  public ContactPhonesKey() {}

  public ContactPhonesKey(Contact contact, String number) {
    this.contact = contact;
    this.number = number;
  }

// getters and setters 

}
```

However, whenever I try to access something by the DAO (when I have created an instance of it by @Autowired) I made for the contact_phones class:

```
public interface ContactPhonesRepository extends CrudRepository<ContactPhones, BigInteger> {

  List<ContactPhones> findByNumberContaining(String number);


  @Query(value ="SELECT * FROM contact_phones cp WHERE cp.contactid= :contactId",
          nativeQuery=true)
  List<ContactPhones> findAllPhonesByContactId(@Param("contactId")BigInteger contactId);

}
```

I am getting an error about not being able to set the ContactPhonesKey class due to reflection. Here's the full error I get:

```
Could not set field value [111456666] value by reflection : [class app.models.relationentities.ContactPhonesKey.number] setter of app.models.relationentities.ContactPhonesKey.number; nested exception is org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: Could not set field value [111456666] value by reflection : [class app.models.relationentities.ContactPhonesKey.number] setter of app.models.relationentities.ContactPhonesKey.number
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a type mismatch on the field `number` between your entity `ContactPhones` and ID Class `ContactPhonesKey`. On the entity, it is declared as `BigInteger`, while on the ID Class, it is declared as `String`.